# C++: Minimization Using Levenberg Marquardt to Solve for Two Variables

Tags: algorithms, optimization, mathematical-programming

I am trying to solve this [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkNfS.png) using C++:

X and Y are both given sets of data.

X = [x1, x2, ... , xn], Y = [y1, y2, ... , yn]

a is a given integer.

The goal is to find a pair z and k that fulfills this equation based on the given data.

I am currently attempting to solve this equation using non-linear least squares with the Levenberg Marquardt algorithm and I am using ALGLIB as the library to implement it in C++.

The issue that I am having is that all the examples I see solve for one variable ([This one in particular](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#example_lsfit_d_nlf)). However, I am trying to find the best pair that fits the solution (z and k).

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) You can use MathJax for typesetting formulae here. 2) Programming is offtopic on [cs.SE]. I'm not sure if this is better suited to [SO] or [scicomp.SE].